# Maven scope provided and transitive dependencies

Tags: maven

I have a dependency with one of the jar and i have marked it as provided in pom xml. It seems only some of the transitive dependency jar are marked as provided and not packaged with the war but others are still scope as compile and  packaged with war libs.Do i need to explicitly mark the scope as provided for all the transitive dependencies.

Dependency in pom xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-ftp:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630262:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.54:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.3.0.redhat-3:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11.redhat-2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-csv:jar:2.17.0.redhat-630262:provided
```

plugin version Details:

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <cdi.api.version>1.2.0.redhat-2</cdi.api.version>
        <javax.inject.version>1.0.0.redhat-6</javax.inject.version>
        <sonar.host.url>http://vfrde2srta0401.agcs.biz:9000</sonar.host.url>
        <xerces.version>2.11.0-22</xerces.version>
        <xmlunit.version>1.6</xmlunit.version>
        <maven.compilerplugin.version>3.7.0</maven.compilerplugin.version>
        <maven.releaseplugin.version>2.5.3</maven.releaseplugin.version>
        <maven.warplugin.version>3.2.0</maven.warplugin.version>
        <maven.jarplugin.version>3.0.2</maven.jarplugin.version>
        <maven.surefireplugin.version>2.20.1</maven.surefireplugin.version>
        <maven.coberturaplugin.version>2.7</maven.coberturaplugin.version>
```

Comment: What is the maven version? Are you using maven-war-plugin ?

Comment: maven 3.5,yes i know specifying the configuration  <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes> in war plugin will not package all dependencies, but i just wanted to understand how the scope is decided for transitive dependencies.

Comment: Which version of maven-dependency-plugin do you use?

Comment: Updated my post with plugin version details.i have used the latest one for all the plugins

Answer (score 10):

As a few people noted already, transitive dependencies of your `provided` scoped dependencies should get scope `provided` in your project. However, the scope can be changed to compile if you have other dependencies in scope `compile` that have the same transitive dependencies. In your case, these two:

```
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11.redhat-2:compile
```

are probably pulled in transitively by another dependency in your pom than `camel-ftp`. You need to run **`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`** to get a hint of why these two got their scope updated to `compile`.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Maven documentation (see table)](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope), if you define a dependency with `provided` scope, transitive dependencies will have the following final scopes depending on their original scope:

- **compile > provided**
- provided > *omitted*
- runtime > provided
- test > *omitted*

A `compile` transitive dependency of your `provided` dependency should then be considered `provided`.

Answer (score 3):

Transitive dependencies scope set based on defined scope. Refer to [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html). You could verify this through changing scope and then verifying dependency tree (mvn dependency:tree).

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
   </dependency>


INFO] \- org.apache.camel:camel-ftp:jar:2.12.2:provided
[INFO]    +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.12.2:provided
[INFO]    +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.49:provided
[INFO]    \- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.3:provided
```

---

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
            <version>2.12.2</version>
 </dependency>

 [INFO] \- org.apache.camel:camel-ftp:jar:2.12.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.12.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.49:compile
[INFO]    \- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.3:compile
```

---

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
 </dependency>


\- org.apache.camel:camel-ftp:jar:2.12.2:runtime
[INFO]    +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.12.2:runtime
[INFO]    +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.49:runtime
[INFO]    \- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.3:runtime
```

---

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
  </dependency>

[INFO] \- org.apache.camel:camel-ftp:jar:2.12.2:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.12.2:test
[INFO]    +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.49:test
[INFO]    \- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.3:test
```

---

Comment: Hi Thanks for detail explanation. But in my case if you see the dependency tree it is not happening in the same way it happened for you.

Comment: I just change the scope of org.apache.camel check the transitive dependencies scope.

Answer (score 0):

i meet same problem, i solve the problem by setting additional provided scope for jar that needs to exclude